# Select an related entity manually

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have an entity that can have an image. This is done using a `OneToMany` relationship. Now I want the user to choose an image. I can of course use a `form field` like this:

```php
$builder->add('image', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Image',
    'class' => 'VendorNameBundle:Image',
    'property' => 'id',
) );
```

It renders as expected a dropdown with all the ids. But what I actually want is only a single field that is hidden and that stores the id of the selected image.

This would work but it seems not like a good thing …

In the **type**:

```php
$builder->add('_image', 'text', array(
    'data' => $object->getImage()->getId(),
    'property_path' => false
));
```

In the **controller**:

```php
$_image = $form["_image"]->getData();
if ($_image) {
    $image  = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VendorNameBundle:Image')->find($_image);
    if ($image) {
        $object->setImage($image);
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I get a hidden text field that contains the ID of the related object and stores the new selected one?

Comment: Do you have javascript that can update a field based on which image is selected? Or will you post back two fields `new_image` and `old_image` for example. In that case why not just overwrite the data using the new field before you persist the entity?

Comment: I actually wanted to update the field and replace the current value. But if I send another value like `new_image`, I still have to update the entity manually like a did in the question, right?

Comment: Correct, I don't think there's anyway around this, unless you hide the select Symfony would automatically create for the image entity and use some javascript to manipulate it to be the value of whatever image the user selected.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too. But I didn't like the fact, that it loads all images for the select box (could get a long list) and I have to hide it using CSS and than change the value there. Seems like more effort than my current solution. Thanks for your opinion.